# Why is the First Lady calling the President a liar?

Tags: independence-day

Independence Day [movie script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Independence-Day.html):

> **INT. HOTEL ROOM - NIGHT**
>
> [Dressed in a night gown, MRS. MARGARET WHITMORE unpacks her briefing papers lays them out on a small desk as she talks. Through the window we SEE Los Angeles at night.]
>
> **MARGARET:** Two in the morning.  I *know* I didn't wake you?
>
> **WHITMORE:** (filtered) As a matter of fact you did.
>
> **MARGARET (smiles) Liar.**

Surely Whitmore was already awake, thinking about Margaret. Why then did she call him a liar?

Comment: Well, you know how presidents are. Everyone always calls them liars.

Comment: He told a teasing lie.  She teasingly called him a liar.  While it is a movie establishing a relationship in 30 seconds or less, there's nothing unclear about this.  Maybe we need to start a Understanding Social Interaction stack, because these types of questions are just getting more frequent and far far more ridiculous.

Comment: @Radhil - That's already been done. :) it's called IPS.

Comment: "Surely Whitmore was already awake, thinking about Margaret. Why then did she call him a liar?" - I don't understand the question. You state yourself that he was awake, right after quoting that he claimed the opposite. What's unexpected about calling that "lying"?

Answer (score 10):

She's admonishing him. This presumably is not the first time she's caught him staying up late to read his paperwork when he should be getting some sleep.

> **MARGARET:** *Two in the morning.  I know I didn't wake you?* **[Why the hell are you still awake?]**
>
> **WHITMORE** (filtered): *As a matter of fact you did.* **[I certainly wasn't up reading my paperwork, honest!]**
>
> **MARGARET** (smiles): *Liar.* **[You clearly *were* awake, you naughty President/husband!]**